# Having a side job with a working permit in Germany

Tags: working-visas, germany

I have a working permit(Aufenthaltserlaubnis) for five years, that is tied to the company which I'm working full time at. I come from a non-EU country.

My Zusatzblatt says: "BESCHÄFTIGUNG NUR GEM. § 2 ABSATZ 1 NR. 3 BESCHV ALS SOFTWARE-ENTWICKLER BEI DER COMPANY ERLAUBT."

My company doesn't impose any restrictions on having a side job.

Am I allowed to work part time as self-employed with this permit? If not, what do I do to achieve this?

Comment: @MarkJohnson  You should put this as a full answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not. You must apply for an adaption of your present permit to allow for self employment. You should include a letter from your present employer stating that they have no objection to this.